# What to do when NewGlobalRef returns NULL?

Tags: java-native-interface

The documentation for the JNI function [`NewGlobalRef`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewGlobalRef) states:

> Returns a global reference, or NULL if the system runs out of memory

However it is not clear to me, if when the function returns `NULL` whether an `OutOfMemoryError` exception has already been thrown by the JVM or not. The documentation does not say that an exception is thrown, if it is not do I need to throw that exception, or should I just return execution to the JVM from JNI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OOM exception will be thrown for you, you should not worry.